# how to fetch the 12 from the given line. url can be change so how we can fetch it in a generic way

Tags: java, string

http://m.flipkart.com/products/12
how to fetch the 12 from  the given line. URL can be change so how we can fetch it in a generic way.

Comment: Please refrain from posting the same question again and again (this is the 4th or 5th almost identical question from you), especially, when it is flagged for closing, or marked as duplicate. Instead, see the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you can use `regex`.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+"); // extract numbers from String
Matcher m = p.matcher("http://m.flipkart.com/products/12");
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Out put:

```
12
```